# How to add list items in the following manner?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I Have a list that contains dbfile,paths and i need to add them to a map inorder to get corresponding values.
**my LIST contains items as like**

```
star
e:\data\star.mdf
e:\data\star.ldf
kiran
e:\data\kiran.mdf
e:\data\kiran.ldf  
hai
e:\data\hai.mdf
e:\data\hai.ldf
```

Now i need to insert them by populating a list as specified format

```
map<string,list<string>>
     |           |
    \/          \/
   databasename   paths info
```

how can i do this.

Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

You could write the following:

```
std::list tempList;
tempList.push_back("e:\data\star.mdf");
tempList.push_back("e:\data\star.ldf");
m.insert(std::make_pair("star", tempList));
```

Note however that the tempList will be copied upon inserting. You might consider this to be an unacceptable performance overhead, which might be solved by using a smart pointer to the list. For example:

std::map>> m;

Comment: i have 100 database like that how to do it for 100

Comment: How to do this one plz explain i have no idea.

Comment: You could use a loop for that.

Comment: That's really not hard. Just parameterize the strings.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a string, like "star" (we'll assume into s), createa map entry:

```
mymap.insert( std::make_pair( s, list <string>() ) );
```

Now you will be reading directory names, into say d. As you have just created the entry, it's safe to use map's operator[]:

```
mymap[s].push_back( d );
```

Comment: How to loop it for a min of 20 times using iterator

Comment: What's the problem? Iterate over the source data and fill the target.

Comment: problem is all that dbs and datapaths available in a list. in the order which i showed above.

Comment: What's the problem again? Loop over the source data. For strings with indices 0, 3, 6, etc create a new list, populate it with the two following strings and add to the map.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is what you want to do:
You need to go through the file line-by-line using `getline()`, than you convert the buffer you used for getline to a string and check with a regular expression if it is a path or a datbasename (you might make your file format more verbose to express this more clearly or you use XML). Then you call the appropriate function to add to the map.
In pseudocode with the assumption that there are only to paths per db:

`infile.open(FILENAME);

while(infile.good()) {

getline(infile, buffer, blength)

string dbName = buffer

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   getline() and to string
addStuffToMap();`

Too lazy to write a working version right now...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a map of names (string) to a list of paths (string). All you need to do is declare exactly that:   std::map< std::string, std::list< std::string> >.  Easy as pie :-)

Try this:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,std::list<std::string> >     dbMap;

    dbMap["star"].push_back("e:\data\star.mdf");
    dbMap["star"].push_back("e:\data\star.ldf");

    dbMap["kiran"].push_back("e:\data\kiran.mdf");
    dbMap["kiran"].push_back("e:\data\kiran.ldf");

    dbMap["hai"].push_back("e:\data\hai.mdf");
    dbMap["hai"].push_back("e:\data\hai.ldf");
}
```